# TDD: Function with a list return good values but it's not working

Tags: c#, list, tdd

I started C# recently and i have to do a project called Ray tracer challenge.
For that, we need to first do some Test driven dev, then it's coding time.
The problem i got is:
The result that needs to be check is returned with <> instead of () and so the test, even if the values are ok, can't pass.

This is my TDD code:

```cs
[Test]
public void Adding()
{
    var a = new List<double>() { 3.5, -2.0, 5.0, 1.0 }; // point
    var b = new List<double>() { -2.0,  3.0, 1.0,  0.0 }; // point

    Assert.AreEqual((a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2], a[3] + b[3]), Addition.Add(string.Empty));
}
```

This is my return function:

```cs
internal static List<double> Add(string numbers)
{
    return new List<double> { 1.5, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0 };
}
```

The result is

```
Adding
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 11
   Duration: 158 ms

  Message: 
      Expected: (1.5d, 1.0d, 6.0d, 1.0d)
      But was:  < 1.5d, 1.0d, 6.0d, 1.0d >
    
  Stack Trace: 
    Tests.Adding() line 17
```

I can't change

```cs
Assert.AreEqual((a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2], a[3] + b[3]), Addition.Add(string.Empty));
```

Could someone explain me please?
PS: I know that testing an addition isn't really worth it, i'm mostly training on basic things.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem has to do with floating point comparison rounding errors: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-in-comparing-floating-point-numbers-and-how-to-compare-them-correctly/

Comment: Your expected expression is a tuple, while your result is a list. You can't compare them directly. Either you also expect a list, or return a tuple in Addion.Add() or compare each element individually.

Answer (score 4):

Your assert compares this: `(a[0] + ... + b[3])` which is a tuple, and this: `new List<double>() { 3.5,... 1.0 }` which is a list.

Since they're different collection types, the comparison does not work as expected.

Either use a `List` as your assert expected value:

```
Assert.AreEqual(new List<double> { a[0] + ... + b[3]}, Addition.Add(string.Empty));
```

Or change your return function to return a `Tuple` like so:

```
{
    return (1.5, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0);
}
```